# Cannot resize APFS partition

Tags: macos, high-sierra, disk-utility, partition, filevault

The drive is encrypted with fileVault.
When i'm trying to grow Macintosh HD to fill Free Space i'm getting with

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 197g
```

I'm getting:

```
....
....
APFS Container Resize error code is -536870167

A problem occurred; undoing all changes

Modifying partition map

Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures
```

[image]
My partition map.

I've already disabled Time Machine and I have no snapshots.
I've executed

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999
```

Full **diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1 197g**
output:

```
Started APFS operation

Aligning grow delta to 40.978.202.624 bytes and targeting a new physical store size of 196.999.999.488 bytes

Determined the maximum size for the targeted physical store of this APFS Container to be 197.103.955.968 bytes

Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1

The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2

Verifying storage system

Using live mode

Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2

Checking volume

Checking the container superblock

Checking the EFI jumpstart record

Checking the space manager

Checking the object map

Checking the APFS volume superblock

Checking the object map

Checking the fsroot tree

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

warning: invalid dstream.default_crypto_id (0x0) for encrypted volume, given apfs_fs_flags (0x8)

Checking the snapshot metadata tree

Checking the extent ref tree

Checking the snapshots

Checking the APFS volume superblock

Checking the object map

Checking the fsroot tree

Checking the snapshot metadata tree

Checking the extent ref tree

Checking the snapshots

Checking the APFS volume superblock

Checking the object map

Checking the fsroot tree

Checking the snapshot metadata tree

Checking the extent ref tree

Checking the snapshots

Checking the APFS volume superblock

Checking the object map

Checking the fsroot tree

Checking the snapshot metadata tree

Checking the extent ref tree

Checking the snapshots

Verifying allocated space

The volume /dev/disk0s2 appears to be OK

Storage system check exit code is 0

Growing APFS Physical Store disk0s2 from 156.021.796.864 to 196.999.999.488 bytes

Modifying partition map

Growing APFS data structures

APFS Container Resize error code is -536870167

A problem occurred; undoing all changes

Modifying partition map

Error: -69606: A problem occurred while resizing APFS Container structures
```

**diskutil list** output

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         156.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                53.7 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +156.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            121.6 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 20.1 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.9 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4
```

**diskutil apfs list** output

```
diskutil apfs list                      
APFS Container (1 found)
|
+-- Container disk1 2EC3AD62-C436-4F8B-9B21-480A8CD1E51A
    ====================================================
    APFS Container Reference:     disk1
    Size (Capacity Ceiling):      156021796864 B (156.0 GB)
    Minimum Size:                 128450334720 B (128.5 GB)
    Capacity In Use By Volumes:   124288155648 B (124.3 GB) (79.7% used)
    Capacity Not Allocated:       31733641216 B (31.7 GB) (20.3% free)
    |
    +-< Physical Store disk0s2 20AE4AE0-FE88-4061-AAB7-6693BD2C3F6D
    |   -----------------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Physical Store Disk:   disk0s2
    |   Size:                       156021796864 B (156.0 GB)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s1 E619B5F7-0B12-35EC-A676-589A806BFE78
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s1 (No specific role)
    |   Name:                      Macintosh HD (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               /
    |   Capacity Consumed:         121472946176 B (121.5 GB)
    |   Decryption Progress:       10.0% (Unlocked)
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s2 DFCC5E43-6DC1-4EDC-9CFD-FAD232AB6965
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s2 (Preboot)
    |   Name:                      Preboot (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         20086784 B (20.1 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s3 336DB3EA-9CE9-46B9-9D8E-E163774777E0
    |   ---------------------------------------------------
    |   APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s3 (Recovery)
    |   Name:                      Recovery (Case-insensitive)
    |   Mount Point:               Not Mounted
    |   Capacity Consumed:         517873664 B (517.9 MB)
    |   FileVault:                 No
    |
    +-> Volume disk1s4 81587B86-6231-40D7-AD7D-C6ADC2AB9413
        ---------------------------------------------------
        APFS Volume Disk (Role):   disk1s4 (VM)
        Name:                      VM (Case-insensitive)
        Mount Point:               /private/var/vm
        Capacity Consumed:         2147635200 B (2.1 GB)
        FileVault:                 No
```

Os version High Sierra 10.13.4 (17E199)

Comment: Did you try resizing the partition from Recovery?

Comment: @pixelomer I tried to resize APFS container (disk1). As you can see, diskutil tells that it will resize disk0s2, which is not Recovery

Comment: What? I am telling you to try resizing the partition ***from*** the Recovery OS. You can boot to Recovery OS by holding Command and R keys after you start your computer.

Comment: I ran into some issues with APFS where it would fail to partition a device unless you told it to partition it with the Available Space-1GB. I.e a 120GB Partition must be created as a 119GB Partition. Can you try manually growing the partition to fill only most of the available space?

Comment: @pixelomer Thanks for advice. I didn't try it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resize the partition immediately after i've disabled the FileVault.

So just disable FileVault > resize partition/APFS container > enable FileVault